# Slack API - Hide some information of profile in response

Tags: slack-api, slack

When using [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) method I'm getting every profile information of every team member. But I need to hide some of this information (because a user can inspect the page, listening to the requests and getting knowledge of the Skype ID or phone number for example). Is there any special argument I can send to Slack API to only return the profile.images & profile.real_name?

Current request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=' + slackAccessToken + '&presence=1&pretty=1',
        data: {format: 'json'}
       };
```

Comment: Whoever you expose the token to will be able to make requests to the Slack API with the same level of permission as the token. So try to never expose the token on the frontend in any way!

Comment: Yes, I've worked on a proxy to hide the information. My problem was about filtering the information of the request, like a abstraction level of the full information. Since I've done the proxy, I filtered the information there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours trying to get this done, the best way of doing this is building a proxy (simple PHP file) as endpoint of your request and filter the informations there. Otherwise this can create a security leak.